# SAS adding new observations for longitudinal data

Tags: sas

I have a longitudinal dataset in SAS with periods of time categorized as either at risk for an event, or not at risk. Unfortunately, some time periods overlap, and I would like to recode them to have a dataset of entirely non-overlapping observations. For example, the dataset currently looks like:

```
Row 1: ID=123; Start=Jan 1, 1999; End=Dec 31, 1999; At_risk="Yes"
Row 2: ID=123; Start=Feb 1, 1999; End=Feb 15, 1999; At_risk="No"
```

The dataset I would like looks like:

```
Row 1: ID=123; Start=Jan  1, 1999; End=Feb  1, 1999; At_risk="Yes"
Row 2: ID=123; Start=Feb  1, 1999; End=Feb 15, 1999; At_risk="No"
Row 3: ID=123; Start=Feb 15, 1999; End=Dec 31, 1999; At_risk="Yes"
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Do you have ETS licensed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vasja may have been suggesting something like this (date level) as an alternative.

I will assume here that the most recent row read in your longitudinal dataset will have priority over any other rows with overlapping date ranges.  If that is not the case then adjust the priority derivation below as appropriate.

Are you sure your start and end dates are correct.  Your desired output still has overlapping dates.  Feb 1 & 15 are both At Risk and not At Risk.  Your End date should be at least one day before the next start date.  Not the same day.  End and Start dates should be contiguous. For that reason coding a solution that produces your desired output (with overlapping dates) is problematic.  The solution below is based on no overlapping dates. You will need to modify it to include overlapping dates as per your required output.

```
/*         Your longitudinal dataset .  */
data orig; 
         format Id 16. Start End Date9.; 
         Id = 123;Start='1jan1999'd; End='31dec1999'd; At_risk="Yes";output; 
         Id = 123;Start='1feb1999'd; End='15feb1999'd; At_risk="No";output; 
run; 

/*         generate a row for each date between start and end dates.  */
/*         Use row number (_n_) to assign priorioty.  */
Data overlapping_dates; 
         set orig; 
         foramt date date9.;
         priority = _n_; 
         do      date = start to end by 1; 
                 output; 
         end; 
Run; 

/*         Get at_risk details for most recent read date according to priority.  */
Proc sql; 
         create  table non_overlapping_dates as 
         select  id, date, at_risk 
         from    overlapping_dates 
         group   by      id, date 
         having  priority eq max (priority) 
         order   by       id, date 
         ; 
Quit; 


/*   Rebuild longitudinal dataset .  */
Data longitudinal_dataset 
    (keep= id start end at_risk)
    ; 
        format id 16. Start End Date9. at_risk $3.;

        set non_overlapping_dates; 
        by id at_risk notsorted; 

        retain start; 

    if  first.at_risk
        then start = date;

/*      output a row to longitudinal dataset if at_risk is about to change or last row for id.  */
        if      last.at_risk 
                then do;
            end = date; 
            output; 
                    end;                     
Run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Such tasks are exercises in debugging of program logic and fighting data assumptions, playing with old/new values...
Below my initial code for the exact example you provided, will surely need some adjustment on real data.

In case there's time overlap on more than current-next record I'm not sure it's doable this way (with reasonable effort). For such cases you'd probably be more effective with **splitting original start - end intervals to day level and then summarize details to new intervals**.

```
data orig;
format Id 16. Start End Date9.;
Id = 123;Start='1jan1999'd; End='31dec1999'd; At_risk="Yes";output;
Id = 123;Start='1feb1999'd; End='15feb1999'd; At_risk="No";output;
run;

proc sort data = orig;
by ID Start;
run;

data modified;
    format pStart oStart pEnd oEnd Date9.;
    set orig;
    length pStart pEnd 8 pAt_risk $3;
    by ID descending End ;

    retain pStart pEnd pAt_risk;

    /* keep original values */
    oStart = Start;
    oEnd = End;
    oAt_risk = At_risk;

    if first.id then do;
        pStart = Start;
        pEnd = End;
        pAt_risk = At_risk;
        /* no output */ 
    end;
    else do;
        if pAt_risk ne At_risk then do;
            if Start > pStart then do;
                put _all_;
                Start = pStart;
                End = oStart;
                At_risk = pAt_risk;
                output;/* first part of time span */
                Start = oStart;
                End = oEnd;
                At_risk = oAt_risk;
                output;/* second part of time span */
                if (End < pEnd ) then do;
                    Start = End;
                    End = pEnd;
                    At_risk = pAt_risk;
                    output; /*third part of time span */
                    /* keep current values as previous record values */
                    pStart = max(oStart, Start);
                    pEnd = End;
                    pAt_risk = At_risk;
                end;
            end;
        end;
    end;
run; 

proc print;run;
```

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there are additional overlaps beyond the current-next records. Your advice about splitting the intervals into separate days was spot on though. Thanks!